# Java char representations for function keys?

Tags: java, unicode, char

I am trying to have a java application press a function key. I have been searching and I  cannot find the unicodes for the F1-F12 function keys on a PC. What are they?

Comment: The don't have Unicode representations because they're *function* keys. They do things. Not type things.

Comment: Why downvotes? This is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: Where are you using it? Are you running it as standalone application or Swing application or Web application or ...?

Comment: @Braj You don't need to tag the owner of a question when commenting on it, they automatically get notified. You tagged the wrong person.

Comment: @AnubianNoob Sorry Will my comment notify to others as well that is already in conversion?

Comment: @Braj uhh, not sure on that one. You can check help.

Comment: Also you should include what you're using to detect a key press.

Comment: I want to automate a function key being pressed on someones PC keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Java [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class's `keyPress` and `keyRelease` methods to script the keyboard, then you probably want [`KeyEvent.VK_F1`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_F1) and its siblings in the [`KeyEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) class.